# Transposing and then exporting a table to a CSV file

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, amazon-redshift

I have an SQL table with 3 columns as such:

[image]

I would like to write a script in Amazon Redshift (running PostgreSQL 8.0.2) that exports the above table to a CSV file transposed. By transposed I mean I would like to create a new column for each `cobrand` (there are 4 distinct values in the `cobrand_id` column) in the CSV file. To illustrate what I want, I included an image (the values are just illustrative):

[image]

When I try:

```
 COPY temp_08.jwn_calc TO 'P:/SQL_New/products_199.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I get the error: `[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "HEADER" Position: 74`.

When I remove "CSV HEADER", I get the error: `[0A000] ERROR: COPY TO file from Xen-tables not supported`

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Are you asking how to transpose the data? Or how to export from Redshift? Or import into Redshift?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein export the transposed data if I'm not mistaken

Comment: I'm trying to export the data in the transposed fashion shown above using postgreSQL.  I'm trying to export the data onto my local PC in the form of a CSV file.

Comment: I'm still confused. Are you looking for the SQL to do the transposition, or the ability to export the data? Or both?

Comment: @ John Rotenstein I'm looking for both.

Answer (score 1):

**TRANSPOSING**

To transpose the data, you'll have to write a query that specifically names each column, such as:

```
SELECT
  qqyy as "Quarter",
  SUM(CASE WHEN cobrand_id = 10001372 THEN sum END) as "10001372",
  SUM(CASE WHEN cobrand_id = 10005244 THEN sum END) as "10005244",
  SUM(CASE WHEN cobrand_id = 10005640 THEN sum END) as "10005640",
  SUM(CASE WHEN cobrand_id = 10006164 THEN sum END) as "10006164"
FROM input_table
GROUP BY qqyy
ORDER BY qqyy
```

**SAVING**

The [`COPY`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html) command in Amazon Redshift can load data from:

- Amazon S3
- Amazon DynamoDB
- An Amazon EMR cluster
- A Linux host running SSH

If you wish to load data into Redshift, you should place a CSV (or a zipped CSV) into an Amazon S3 bucket and [use the `COPY` command to import the data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html).

If you wish to **export** the data from Redshift, [use the `UNLOAD` command to created zipped CSV files in Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html). It is not possible to directly download results from Redshift via the UNLOAD command. Alternatively, your SQL client that runs locally on your computer might have the ability to **save** query results to a file.

The error you received is due to the fact that you attempted to access the filesystem of the Redshift host computer (`P:/SQL_New/products_199.csv`). This is not permitted, since you have no login access to the host computer.

If you already have an SQL query that transforms the data to what you want, the use the `UNLOAD` command to export it:

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT...FROM...') CREDENTIALS ... TO 's3://my-bucket/output.csv'
```

Comment: Hi John - I'm accessing the Redshift via a SQL IDE.  I need the code to transpose the data as shown, preferably in SQL.  The path I would like to save the data to (P:/SQL_New/products_199.csv) sits on my personal PC.

Comment: Thanks @ John Rotenstein, but I'm looking to export the data to my local/personal PC, not to S3.  P:/ drive is a drive on my PC.

Comment: You *CANNOT* export to a local drive. The only way is to `UNLOAD` to an Amazon S3 bucket and then download from there. The only alternative is to save query results from your SQL IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run this in a script, you can use psql, format the query to print csv, and output the result to a file. Something like:

```
psql -t -h HOST -p 5439 -U USER -d DBNAME -o "P:/SQL_New/products_199.csvaf" -c \
"SELECT
  qqyy || ',' ||
  SUM(CASE WHEN cobrand_id = 10001372 THEN sum END)  || ',' ||
  SUM(CASE WHEN cobrand_id = 10005244 THEN sum END)  || ',' ||
  SUM(CASE WHEN cobrand_id = 10005640 THEN sum END)  || ',' ||
  SUM(CASE WHEN cobrand_id = 10006164 THEN sum END) 
FROM input_table
GROUP BY qqyy
ORDER BY qqyy"
```

If you are scheduling this script, you need to configure your passwords in ~/.pgpass